# $A$ is a ring and $I$ is an ideal, an element $x \in A$ maps to an invertible element of $A/I$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

I am having a hard time understanding the following question

> Let $A$ be a ring and $I \subset \operatorname{nilrad}A$ an ideal; if $x \in A$ maps to an invertible element of $A/I$, prove that $x$ is invertible in $A$.

What does

> $x$ maps to an invertible element of $A/I$

mean?
This question originally has two parts. In the first part, we prove that if $a$ is a unit and $x$ in nilpotent, then $a+x$ is again a unit. I just could not understand the second part of the question.

Comment: It means that the coset $x + I$ is invertible within $A / I$.

Comment: So, it means the canonical homomorphism?

Comment: Dear Mrtired, if I were you I would unaccept the answer you accepted (because it is incorrect) and accept Bernard's answer.

Comment: I used Bernard's answer since it used the first problem as well. But my problem was actually understanding the statement of the problem, the rest is doable for me. But you are right, thanks.

Comment: Mrtired: thanks!!! (I discovered your comment by chance. In such a situation it's better to add an `@Pierre-YvesGaillard`. (I didn't put an `@Mrtired` because you're automatically notified when you get a comment to a post of yours.))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

‘$x+I$ is a unit in $A/I$’ means there exists $y\in A$ such that $xy\in 1+I$, i.e. there exists $i\in I$ such that $xy=1+i$. By the first question, since $i$ is nilpotent, $1+i$ is a unit, in other words, there exists an element $u\in A$ such that
$$(1+i)u=1,\quad\text{or }\;(xy)u=x(yu)=1,$$
which shows $x$ is a unit, with inverse $yu$.

Answer (score 1):

The map in "maps" is the canonical projection $x \mapsto x+I$ from the object $A$ to its quotient $A/I$.

Since all of $I$ in $A$ maps to the additive identity in $A/I$, no element of $I$ maps to an invertible element of $A/I$.  Less specifically, any non-unit in $A/I$ is not invertible so all preimages of non-units are not invertible.